# Field editor in QGIS 3.0 no Text edition button

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I used QGIS 2.18 and now I use QGIS 3.0 under Windows 10 in Spanish versions.

In the field editor in version 2.18 each field had his button "Text edition" but in version 3.0 that button doesn't appear. In the next images you can see what I mean, the first is from version 2.18 and the second is from version 3.0.

Can someone help me? Have they moved that option to another window?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TaDC.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF1Te.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Settings about 'Edit Widget' in QGIS 2.x was moved to 'Attributes Form' tab in QGIS 3.x.

To perform widget settings of a field, you get 'Attributes Form' tab, select a field, select a widget type and edit settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this to help others avoid my foolish mistake (QGIS 3.4 on Windows 10).

In the Attributes Form Kadir Şahbaz shows you how to find, the dropdown arrow on the combo box with options for the different widgets you can use on a field does not show up until the dialog is wide enough for the arrow to appear on the right.  My dialog box was fairly wide, but not wide enough, so I thought there were no options available.

So, if you don't see any widget options, just widen the dialog until you see the dropdown arrow, and use it reveal the options.