# QGIS 2map plugin issue - no map tiles provided for QGIS 3x (3.8)

Tags: qgis, leaflet, openlayers, mapbox, api

Following the example described here:

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html

I am trying to do the same with QGIS 3.8.

The process in QGIS is simple, after seeking the following steps, being spread out in different places as the program has been update.
Example here:
[Field editor in QGIS 3.0 no Text edition button](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291792/field-editor-in-qgis-3-0-no-text-edition-button)

But the major problem for me is transfer this data into APIs provided (OpenLayers, Leaflet, Mapbox). After finish my process I get my data, but without any map tile...

[image]

what I can see already in the preview mode:

Thenceforth the map is blank even after export:

[image]

what I believe is caused by lack of option available in QGIS 2x, where user could select the map tilelayer at this step:

[image]

which diesn't appear in the QGIS 3.8.

Could anybody let me know, where can I find this option? I would like to have a full map exported not only the GeoJSON (layer) data.

Answer (score 2):

Looks Like I found an answer for it.
The problem has been reported in this link:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/623

which says, that since QGIS 3x the layer selection option in QGIS2web plugin has been deprecated and moved into the general basemaps repository:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/wiki/basemaps

from where you can connect into the XYZ tiles as shown in the link above.

Then your geoJSON data should be visible on the map tile instead of blank background.

[image]

[image]

[image]